# Almacenamiento de una BD con EF en proyecto asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server

Tengo una aplicacion web mvc que almacena de forma local dentro del proyecto 2 archivos con extension .mdf y .ldf los cuales tengo entendido son los mismo que utiliza Sql Server y estos ahora estan dentro de la carpeta app_data que fue generada con EF.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mis consultas:
¿Esta practica es nueva o siempre se podia llevar la BD dentro del proyecto del sistema? ya que al desarrollar una aplicacion de escritorio anteriormente con winform se requeria que este instalado sql server y que contenga la BD en la pc a utilizarse dentro de ella, para poder recien conectarse a ella e iniciar la interaccion de datos.

¿Al tener mi BD dentro del proyecto ASP.NET MVC es posible que el servidor donde sea almacenado la aplicacion ya no requiera la instalacion del gestor de datos MSSQL SERVER y que ventajas y desventajas me trae usar esta forma de almacenamiento local?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**>>¿Esta practica es nueva o siempre se podia llevar la BD dentro del proyecto del sistema?**

no es una practica nueva, ya desde VS2010 se podria adjuntar dinamicamente una base de datos al servicio de sql server

**>>al desarrollar una aplicacion de escritorio anteriormente con winform se requeria que este instalado sql server y que contenga la BD**

En un desarrollo `Windows Application` tambien se puede realizar un attch dinamico, solo es cuestion de adjuntar el .mdf en el proyecto, esto hara que el VS realice una copia al \bin\Debug y se conecte a este de forma dinámica

Aqui

[Visual Studio Base de Datos integradas al proyecto](http://ltuttini.blogspot.pe/2012/11/visual-studio-base-de-datos-integradas.html)

lo explico usando un .sdf (Sql Compact), pero con un .mdf aplica de la misma forma si tiene el servicio de Sql Server ejecutando de forma local.

**>>¿Al tener mi BD dentro del proyecto ASP.NET MVC es posible que el servidor donde sea almacenado la aplicacion ya no requiera la instalacion del gestor de datos MSSQL SERVER**

me temo que no, el attach es dinámico pero se requiere del servicio de Sql Server

**>>que ventajas y desventajas me trae usar esta forma de almacenamiento local?**

La principal ventaja es que la db esta integrada con el desarrollo en el mismo proyecto, por tanto mover la solucion de carpetas o de un equipo a otro es transparente y te llevas los datos junto al código.

Mas que nada facilita mientas desarrollas que este todo integrado, aunque luego en un deploy en produccion sería aconsejable que la db este integrada al servicio de Sql Server.

Comment: El link no redirecciona hacia tu explicacion, pero ya lo encontre en google :) y lo edite, en espera de revision por pares. mil Gracias :)